# Symfony - problem with Exception pages in prod environment

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

I was trying to google this issue but I am unable to find anything helpful.
I can't get the default error handling pages to work in the prod evironment.
In dev I have the normal debug screens.
What I am seeing in the prod evironment is (instead 404 page)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError: 
There are no registered paths for namespace "Exception". 
in C:\dev\proj\vendor\twig\twig\src\Loader\FilesystemLoader.php:205
```

My understanding was that I only need to create the Exception folder in Resources in case I want to overwrite them? But even when I did it was still not working.

My routing for errors:

```
_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error
```

Comment: You probably forgot a use somewhere in your application! :)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure of creating a custom error twig template in:

```
app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig
```

example:

```
<title>Page not found</title>
{% block body %}
    <div>
        {{ exception.message }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and run `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: Thanks but it did not help, btw, is that not needed only in case when you want to overwrite default templates?

Comment: @GrumpyHat _errors: routing seems used only to test error pages during development https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller/error_pages.html#testing-error-pages-during-development , have you _errors route in routing.yml?